# The requested resource is not available on my bookstore application

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I keep getting this error but dont know how to figure it out. This is my complete web.xml file as I believe that is solely a web.xml issue. Or is there any other file that could be causing this requested resource problem...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

this is my bookcontroller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/listBooks" })
    public String listBooks(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("book", new Book());
        map.put("bookList", bookService.listBooks());

        return "/book/listBooks";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/get/{bookId}")
    public String getBook(@PathVariable Long bookId, Map<String, Object> map) {

        Book book = bookService.getBook(bookId);

        map.put("book", book);

        return "/book/bookForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book,
            BindingResult result) {

        bookService.saveBook(book);

        /*
         * Note that there is no slash "/" right after "redirect:" So, it
         * redirects to the path relative to the current path
         */
        return "redirect:listBooks";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{bookId}")
    public String deleteBook(@PathVariable("bookId") Long id) {

        bookService.deleteBook(id);

        /*
         * redirects to the path relative to the current path
         */
        // return "redirect:../listBooks";

        /*
         * Note that there is the slash "/" right after "redirect:" So, it
         * redirects to the path relative to the project root path
         */
        return "redirect:/book/listBooks";
    }
```

this is my root-context.xml code

```
<context:component-scan base-package="np.com.mshrestha.bookstore" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <!-- <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>np.com.mshrestha.bookstore.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

I can also see this warning on my console

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bookstore/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Please how can I resolve this error once and for all in my application. Many thanks

Comment: Please post your webcontroller code

Comment: Do you have something which maps to bookstore in webcontroller?

Comment: please post code for root-servlet.xml

Comment: I have done that @LearningPhase

Comment: I don't see any thing mapped to bookstore so the error is correct

Comment: Please how do I do the mapping to the bookstore

Comment: When I launch my application it takes that url by defualt. I have been trying to change it but no way. Even if I can try some thing like this, bookstore/book.jsp still it doesnt work. How do I fix this route issue permanently

Comment: Its not working on /listBooks

Comment: why do my application launch with /bookstore by default. Lets me begin from that point

Comment: You have to make some changes to the web.xml. Can you please try /bookstore/listBooks and see if it works

Comment: what changes do I make please?

Comment: did not work .....

Comment: I know when I was building jdbc and dynamic web application, there is what we call ContextPath. That defines the entry point to your application. Please how do I define in a Spring Maven project

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109872/jng-help

Comment: @LearningPhase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792005/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-method-supp